# Mongoose where, I can't filter array

Tags: node.js, mongoose, where-clause

This is my model

```
var boxSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    link: String,
    mark: String,
    price: Number,
    format: Array,
});
```

Routes

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

var where = {};

if(req.param('mark')) {
    where.mark= req.param('mark');
}

if(req.param('format')) {
    where.format = req.param('format');
}

var perPage = 9;
var page = parseInt(req.param('page')) || 1;

Box
    .find(where)
    .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
    .limit(perPage)
    .exec(function(err, Boxs) {
        Box.count(where).exec(function(err, count) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect('/');
            }

            var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;

            if(fullUrl.indexOf('?') == -1) {
                fullUrl = fullUrl + '?';
            }

            fullUrl = fullUrl.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, '').replace('&page=' + page, '');

            res.render('./configurator/box/index', {
                Boxs: Boxs,
                current: page,
                pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage),
                URL: fullUrl
            });

        });
    });
});
```

Boxes can have this formats mITX, ATX, eATX, mATX, mITX, CEB, EEB, UCFF,Mini-STX. Of course one box can have more formats.

When i send GET request with one format for example http://localhost:3000/boxes?format=ATX. It works good because i get only boxes which have format ATX.

Problem is when i want show boxes which have for example format ATX or CEB. (http://localhost:3000/boxes?format=ATX&format=+CEB). I don't get any boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first you need to send multiple `format` values to the server as follows

```
http://localhost:3000/boxes?format=ATX&format=CEB
```

`Express` will parse the query-string values into an array that accessible from `req.query`

```js
console.log(req.query.format);
// ['ATX', 'CEB']
```

Now that you have filter parameters, you can build your mongo query using [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator

```js
const where = {};
if (req.query.format) {
    if (Array.isArray(req.query.format)) {
        where.format = {
            $in: req.query.format
        };
    } else {
        where.format = req.query.format;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Simion Happy to hear. You can mark the answer as the correct one

Comment: Sorry man. I wanted to mark your answer but I have low reputation